# Can't import ggplot module in iPython

Tags: ipython, python-ggplot

I'm trying to use ggplot in an Anaconda iPython notebook. I ran `%matplotlib inline` and `from ggplot import *`, but I just get the following error:

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-02aeb6e281ab> in <module>()
----> 1 from ggplot import *
ImportError: No module named ggplot
```

Where in the Anaconda launcher can modules be imported?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably need to install ggplot via the terminal first. Assuming you already have pip installed, run this in the terminal:`$ pip install ggplot`

You should see the package download.  Then go back to your notebook and run your same commands again.

Comment: The assumption regarding `pip` is that you have Python 2.7.9 or later, with which it is included by default. If for whatever reason you don't have it, [download it here](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/installing.html)